# How to use compose test rule inside java test class with mix of compose and xml views

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso

I am attempting to write UI tests for certain views, where some tests are already implemented in Java. I also aim to include tests for Compose views. However, in my attempts, using either test tags or content descriptions has not been recognized by Espresso. Additionally, I am facing challenges in integrating the Compose test rule inside a Java test class. If someone has successfully achieved this or can provide suggestions related to this matter, it would greatly help me understand how to accomplish this.

[image]

Comment: Very first is We can not use composeTestRule inside java test class.

Answer (score 0):

Add the required dependencies to your project:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:<VERSION>'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test:<VERSION>'
```

Then create a **Compose Test Rule** instance in your test class.

Now use the `setContent` method of the Compose Test Rule to set the Compose content for your test:

```
composeTestRule.setContent {
    // Your Compose content here.
}
```

Then use the `onNode` method of the **Compose Test Rule** to interact with **Compose** views:

```
composeTestRule.onNode(hasText("Test message.")).performClick()
```

Finally to interact with **XML views**, you can use the regular **Espresso** methods:

```
onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click())
```

Comment: I want to use compose test rule inside existing java test class.